# Test whether current org buffer has at least one heading

Tags: org-mode

What's a good method of testing whether the current buffer contains at least one heading?

This is the best solution that initially came to mind:

```
(> (length (org-map-entries nil nil 'file)) 0)
```

Comment: How about re-search-forward/backward for the regexp matching a generalized heading, with a save-excursion?  Since you'd only be making one pass, it would be extremely quick.

Comment: @lawlist's function would be a one-liner:  `(defun any-headings-p ()
  (save-excursion (re-search-forward "^\\*+ " nil t)))`

Comment: @Dan -- with a `(goto-char (point-min))` just after `save-excursion`.